# XML Deserialization base64 string to bytes

Tags: xml, base64, byte, deserialization

Hi I have a need to deserialize an XML file which contains an image in base64 string. When I deserialize the XML the image is straight away populated as bytes by the following class. Which pretty much eliminates the need to do anything fancy and I write the image from those bytes. However a few images print as corrupt while others are perfectly fine. I need to resolve why few images are corrupt. Either the source is incorrect or I am missing something.

My question is 'is it necessary to use Convert.FromBase64String() function to convert the base64 string to bytes?' Doing this doesn't really make a difference anyway.

I suppose that the XML deserialization process automatically does that job

Can anybody please provide a credible source for whatever the case maybe?

```
Public Class Graphics_Data
  Private _Image_Graphic As List(Of Byte())
  <XmlElement("Image_Graphic")>
  Public Property Image_Graphic As List(Of Byte())
    Get
        Return _Image_Graphic
    End Get
    Set(value As List(Of Byte()))
        _Image_Graphic = value
    End Set
 End Property
End Class
```

Comment: what language/library? It depends a lot on that.

Comment: @Fakrudeen This is in VB.Net and I am using XmlSerializer.Deserialize() function to deserialize the XML. And I would have thought that function automatically detects the encoding and does the job of converting, which seems the case in my testing.